# Expressing one line in terms of others in triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How can $b$ be expressed in terms of $d$ and $D$? Can't figure this out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition of $\tan\theta$

Since $\tan\alpha=\dfrac{b}{d}$ and $\tan\beta=\dfrac{b}{D}$,

$$b = d \tan \alpha = D \tan \beta$$